# Is there a package that allows indoor positionning using iBeacons?

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am trying to build a Xamarin.Forms app that enables indoor positionning using iBeacons. For now, i can only do testing on Android.

Before I jump into trying to adapt existing native packages, I wanted to know if there were some existing libraries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to implement this? Can you share your findings and final solution you settled on? Would really help me as I'm looking for a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

Indoor positioning using iBeacon is a complex feature that requires both HW (iBeacon devices) and SW -- all components to setup location map, iBeacon position, all logic related to position calculation, and so on. So building this all from scratch is quite a complex task. Thus, I suggest trying something that already exists.

For example, Estimote has indoor positioning feature in their SDK, but from what I know, they use Fingerprinting method to calculate position which is a bit inaccurate; Leantegra ([Leantegra GitHub](https://github.com/leantegra)), in turn, posesses this functionality as well, and uses Multilateration method which is more accurate. So, feel free to try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwer. I saw that Estimote had a indoor positionning feature, but unfortunately I have beacons that are not Estimote. I found a library for Xamarin.Android there: https://github.com/chrisriesgo/Android-AltBeacon-Library.  It is able to give me distances and other infos.                                                             I am planning on writing the trilateration methods, not really knowing how ambitious that is..

Answer (score 0):

Trilateration is only the first step, to get an appropriate accuracy, you need to use Multilateration method -- calculate position based on signal to multiple (more then 3) beacon devices. If represent ibeacon devices as circle with radius equal to signal strength, you will get a lot of possible disposition, where the calculation of a position becomes quite a complex task...